# EF Core 3 Clustered indexing using fluent API not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-3.1

I have a .Net core 3.1 API with EF core code first migrations enabled where I am trying to add a clustered index on a non PK column.

I have a Vehicle entity:

```
public class Vehicle 
{
    // PK and has clustered index by default
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // FK and needs to be clustered
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CompanyId))]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

I created a code first migration for the above model, then updated the database.
At this point the table has PK as `Id` with clustered index and `CompanyId` just as FK.

To remove clustered index from `Id` and to add Clustered Index on `CompanyId` I wrote the following in Fluent API in the `OnModelCreating()` method

```
// Remove ClusteredIndex from PK
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().HasIndex(m => m.Id).IsUnique(true).IsClustered(false);
// Add clustered index on CompanyId
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().HasIndex(m => m.CompanyId).IsUnique(false).IsClustered(true);
```

When I run the API, I can see that the above ccode does execute but it has no effect on the SQL DB and does not change the indexing as desired.

[image]

What am I missing here? How do I add a clustered index on `CompanyId` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used good old SQL inside the Migrations to fix this.

First created an extension method for `MigrationBuilder`:

```
public static void CreateNonPKClusteredIndex(this MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder,
    string tableNameWithSchema,
    string pkConstraintName, string pkColumnName,
    string nonClusteredIndexName, string clusteredColumnName)
{
    // Change PK clustered index to non clustered
    migrationBuilder.Sql($"ALTER TABLE {tableNameWithSchema} DROP CONSTRAINT {pkConstraintName}");
    migrationBuilder.Sql($"ALTER TABLE {tableNameWithSchema} ADD CONSTRAINT {pkConstraintName} PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED({pkColumnName})");

    // Update CompanyId index to clustered index
    migrationBuilder.Sql($"Drop Index {nonClusteredIndexName} on {tableNameWithSchema}");
    migrationBuilder.Sql($"CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX[{nonClusteredIndexName}] ON {tableNameWithSchema}({clusteredColumnName} ASC)");
}
```

Then simply called it inside the `Up()` in the respective migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateNonPKClusteredIndex("Core.Vehicles",
    "PK_Vehicles", "Id",
    "IX_Vehicles_CompanyId", "CompanyId");
```

Result:
[image]